# What to do if about page is showing below the home page instead of another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This one is my output image for your better understanding what i am trying to ask

[image]

This is my file where the link is to be clicked in this i am just trying on link to be clicked. When i click link you can see the output comes at down part of the same page instead of on the other page

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="footer-col">
    <h4 className="h"> About Order</h4>
    <ul className="u1">
      <li>
        <Link to={{ pathname: "/aboutus" }}>About us</Link>
      </li>
      <li><a>Track My Orders</a></li>
      <li><a>Checkout</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/aboutus" element={<Aboutus />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This one is my About us file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Combinecases from "../Cases/combinecases";
import './Aboutus.css'

class Aboutus extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="h12">HIIIIIII</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Aboutus;
```

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sure here I have added some main codes for your understanding please let me know if you want to know more and help me out please.

Comment: The code you've shared is only rendering one route, e.g. "page", on the `"/aboutus"` path. Can you clarify in better detail what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Sure that's why i have shared image also for your better understanding. The issue is when i click the Link 'About Us' the content of the about us page is showing below the page instead of on the new one page. You can see in the image also the content is displayed below the image instead of showing it on the another page. Hope you are clear with my issue please help me out and let me know if want anything from my side.